# Error while trying to pass Byte through TCP connection

Tags: scala, akka, byte, akka-stream

I need to pass byte like "0x02" through tcp connection and process it on a server. Code of client is here:

```
package protocol
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Source, Tcp}
import akka.util.ByteString
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Source, Tcp}
import akka.util.ByteString
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

class UpperServiceClient(ip: String, port: Int) {
    def run = {
        implicit val system = ActorSystem("ClientSys")
        implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

        val a1 = Array("0x02", "0x02").toSeq
        val testInput = a1.map(ByteString(_))
        val result: Future[ByteString] = Source(testInput).via(Tcp().outgoingConnection(ip, port)).
          runFold(ByteString.empty) { (acc, in) => acc ++ in }

        val res: ByteString = Await.result(result, 10.seconds)
    }
}
```

But IDEA shows me error:

> Type mismatch, expected: Iterable[NotInferedT], actual: Seq[ByteString]

What should I do to pass "0x02" as whole byte?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Source`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.14/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source$.html#apply[T](iterable:scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[T]):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.NotUsed]) factory method that you're using expects an immutable `Iterable`. By default, calling `.toSeq` on an array returns a mutable `Seq`. One way to address this is to call `.toList` instead:

```
val a1 = Array("0x02", "0x02").toList
```

Comment: Thank you, now there is no error. But now the server reads a new byte, like "0", and not a single "0x02". Server-side written on Python and output of the code like: `print(sock.recv(1))` is `b'0'`. Have you any ideas to solve that problem? I think, the problem is still on client side.

Comment: I have found a solution. Byte strings should be without quotes, like `(0x02, 0x02)`. Now it's working well. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @alexandrgomd you could maybe consider accepting this as the right answer. This way, this question won't appear anymore in the list of unanswered questions ... :) Thanks!